# If $B \ (\supseteq A)$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module, then $B$ is integral over $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm going through a proof of the statement:

---

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative rings.
If $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, then all $b \in B$ are integral over $A$.

---

Proof:

Let $\{c_1, ... , c_n\} \subseteq B$ be a set of generators for $B$ as an $A$-module, i.e $B = \sum_{i=1}^n Ac_i$. Let $b \in B$ and write $bc_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}c_j $ with $a_{ij} \in A$, which says that $(bI_n - (a_{ij}))c_j = 0 $ for $ 1 \leq j \leq n$. Then we must have that $\mathrm{det}(bI_n - (a_{ij})) = 0 $. This is a monic polynomial in $b$ of degree $n$.

Why are we not done here? The proof goes on to say:

Write $1 = \alpha_1 c_1 + ... + \alpha_n c_n$, with the $\alpha_i \in A$. Then $\mathrm{det}(bI_n - (a_{ij})) = \alpha_1 (\mathrm{det}...) c_1 + \alpha_2 (\mathrm{det}...) c_2 + ... + \alpha_n (\mathrm{det}...) c_n = 0$. Hence every $b \in B$ is integral over $A$.

I understand what is being done here on a technical level, but I don't understand *why* it's being done. I'd appreciate a hint/explanation. Thanks

Comment: Dear Pablo: What's behind this argument are, I think, the following facts. (a) Each $A$-module $M$ is a quotient of a free module $F_M$. (b) $M$ is finitely generated iff (a) holds for some $F_M$ of finite rank. (c) Each $A$-linear map $\phi:M\to N$ admits a lift (obvious definition) $\Phi:F_M\to F_N$ (obvious notation). - I don't know if this is the kind of things you're looking for, but if it is, and if you want more details, I'd be happy to try to spell them out.

Answer (score 13):

You prematurely write "Then we must have that $\mathrm{det}(bI_n - (a_{ij})) = 0$".
At that stage you can only deduce (by multiplying by the adjoint of your matrix on the left) that all the $det\cdot c_i =0$.
However writing $1 = \alpha_1 c_1 + ... + \alpha_n c_n$ and multiplying by $det$ you do get

$$det=det\cdot 1= \alpha_1\cdot det\cdot c_1+...+\alpha_n\cdot det\cdot c_n=\alpha_1\cdot 0+...+\alpha_n\cdot 0=0$$

(This is a variation on  the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, according to which the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix annihilates that matrix.)

Comment: Doesn't it just come down to the fact that $c_i$ can't be $0$ for all $i$?

Comment: Dear @Pablo: no. Even if $c_{i_0}\neq 0$, you cannot deduce from  $\det \cdot c_{i_0}=0$ that $\det=0$ because $B$ might have zero-divisors and $c_{i_0}$ might be one of them.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to phrase it, slightly different to Georges's answer and comments,
is as follows:

In the first paragraph of the proof, $B$ could be replaced by any f.g. $A$-module $M$, and $b$ could any endomorphism of that $A$-module. What we conclude is that every $\varphi \in End_A(M)$ is integral over $A$.
In particular, if $M$ is in fact a $B$-module, then we conclude that *the image* of $B$ in $End_A(M)$ is integral over $A$.

The point of the second paragraph is to observe that (since $B$ is a ring with $1$), the natural map $B \to End_A(B)$ (given by $B$ acting on itself through
multiplication) is injective, so that $B$ coincides with its image in $End_A(B)$.  Only after making this additional observation can we conclude that
$B$ is integral over $A$.

Just as something to think about, what you'll see is that the argument proves
that if $B$ is an $A$-algebra which admits a *faithful* module which is f.g. over $A$, then $B$ is integral over $A$.  On the other hand, if $B$ just admits a module that is f.g. over $A$, but not necessarily faithful, then we can't conclude that $B$ is integral over $A$.  (See if you can find a counterexample.)